# Unable to reach Azure virtual machine on port 9000 for Sonarqube installation

Tags: debian, azure, virtual-machines, sonarqube

I'm trying to install `sonarqube@7.3` with `postgresql` on a `Debian 9 Stretch` virtual machine hosted with Microsoft Azure. Everything works properly except that I can't browse with my real physical machine at *mydns.myregion.cloudapp.azure.com:9000*.

Any clues to work on this ?

---

**What you'll need to know :**

- Sonarqube is working (logs tell that Sonarqube is up and running properly)
- nmap localhost shows :

  - 22/tcp   open  ssh
  - 80/tcp   open  http
  - 5432/tcp open  postgresql
  - 9000/tcp open  cslistener
  - 9001/tcp open  tor-orport
- Many tries on `sonar.properties` but at the moment, the file is very close from the default one except for the DB credentials section and sonar.web.host entry with the ip address of my VM.
- No lines in the *access.log* file

*NB :*
I don't have administrator rights on the VM so my options are limited on the azure portal...

**Log of web.log** :

`2018.10.11 09:29:28 ERROR web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-13.69.61.190-9000"]
 java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:982)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:245)
     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:66)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:997)
     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367)
     at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:61)
     at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:51)
     at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:113)
     at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:100)
     at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:91)
 2018.10.11 09:29:28 ERROR web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] Fail to start web server`

*Edit : While moving sonar.properties to localhost, `curl http://localhost:9000` executed from the VM works and gave me the web page in shell, this is definitely some Azure and ip configuration...*

Answer (score 0):

> 2018.10.11 09:29:28 ERROR web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-13.69.61.190-9000"]
>    java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address

*There's your problem* - That typically means that the port's in use for some reason. Java's syntax is a bit odd there I guess. Looking at your ports in use with this in mind and the line `9000/tcp open cslistener` pops out - the ports in use. While I'm not familiar with sonarqube, using a different port would probably sort it out.

[The docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server) suggests that `9000` is your default port (which ties in nicely with my diagnosis) and to fix that you need to edit `sonar.properties` - I believe there should be a line reading `sonar.web.port=9000` which can be altered to any open port.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. But don't you think that it's because SonarQube is actually using it (_cslistener_ can be part of SonarQube...) ?
The problem in this is that i cannot open ports myself and i've already asked someone else to open the 9000 one to use SonarQube with it.
Futhermore, have you noticed that i use my **physical** machine's browser to access to my url ? I'm thinking that the problem is more relative with this, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network).

Comment: Well SonarQube isn't starting, so its already running or something else is there. [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176613/what-is-cslistener/176668#176668) seems to be an identical problem. You will *not* be able to start sonarqube without having an available port for it to listen on.

Comment: This is my bad for commenting that fast... But when SonarQube is not running the port isn't in use (e.g :  blank output from sudo fuser -v 9000/tcp)
 I'm reconsidering previous problems...